# Getting the input from a PUT method in Web.py

Tags: http, web.py, put

I'm using the following code in my server program:

```
class AddLibSong:
  def PUT(self):
  db = MahData.getDBConnection()
  songs = json.loads(web.input().to_add)
  addToLibrary(songs)
  return
```

But for some reason when I do a PUT with the data:

```
"to_add=[ { "album" : "Unknonwn", "artist" : "Unknonwn", "host_lib_id" : "1", "is_deleted" :
"false", "server_lib_id" : "-1", "song" : "Moneytalks" } ]"
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 228, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 409, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/application.py", line 385, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "/Users/kurtis/sandbox/udj/webserver/Library.py", line 114, in PUT
    song = json.loads(web.input().to_add)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web/utils.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError, k
AttributeError: 'to_add'

127.0.0.1:51096 - - [29/Sep/2011 19:02:58] "HTTP/1.1 PUT /add_songs_to_library" - 500 Internal Server Error
```

Anybody know why this is? I think I saw something about Web.py begin only able to get input if given a POST or GET but I didn't see anything in the source code that should prevent this.

Comment: Normally a REST service answering a PUT should say very little more than HTTP response code 200. In your case, the request is failing probably in response to some incorrect values; the JSON represents an array with one element, an object with keys and values. I hope this helps

Comment: So turns out I posted an incorrect error message. I have fixed this. You'll see the problem is with an AttributeError now.

Comment: Just tried changing this from a PUT to a POST, everything works now. Why can't I get the input on a PUT request?

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, if you want more details on how to use PUT with WebPy I would advice you [this](http://johnpaulett.com/2008/09/20/getting-restful-with-webpy/) great link.

To make it work on the last version of webpy you should change the "main" code to that:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app=web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```